# Como sumar y dividir dos array extraidos de una consulta de mysql en php

Tags: php, mysql

Hola necesito hacer una formula en base a los resultados de las consultas que hago en mysql tengo una tabla que se llama **solicitud_mante** del cual usare el campo que se llama **Tipo_mante** en este campo guardo 5 tipos de mantenimiento **(diferido, preventivo, overhoul, predictivo e inmediato)** la formula la realizara en base a estos mantenimientos que seria así:

(todos los mantenimientos excepto el inmediato) = mante 
(todos los mantenimientos inmediatos) = inme

**RESUL = mante / (mante + inme)** pero no puedo hacer esta formula, pensé que era tal cual solo usar el simbolo " + " y " / " si imprimo esto por ejemplo **$ru = $mante + $inme;** me imprime esto **[43],[1],** lo cual deberia de dar como resultado un **[44]** entonces haber si me pueden ayudar con esto, este seria mi código php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include "conexion.php";
?>

            <?php
            $mys= "SELECT monthname(Fecha_soli) as Mes, count(Tipo_mante) as Mante
            from solicitud_mante
            where Tipo_mante not in('Correctivo Inmediato')
            group by year(Fecha_soli), month(Fecha_soli)";
            ?>


            <?php
            $mysq= "SELECT monthname(Fecha_soli) as Mes, count(Tipo_mante) as Inme
            from solicitud_mante
            where Tipo_mante = 'Correctivo Inmediato'
            group by year(Fecha_soli), month(Fecha_soli)";
            ?>

        <?php

            $consul=$cone->query($mys);
                $consul2=$cone->query($mysq);


                if($consul->num_rows >0)
                {
                    while($row = $consul->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                     $sam[]= "[".$row["Mante"]."],";
                 }
             }

             if($consul2->num_rows >0)
             {
                while($row = $consul2->fetch_assoc())
                {
                   $inme[] =  "[".$row["Inme"]."],";
                }
            }

            $re = $sam;
            $ri = $sam + $inme;

            echo implode($ri);

        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Porque agregas los corchetes?

Comment: no entien do que intentas hacer aqui: `$inme[] =  "[".$row["Inme"]."],";`, es mejor que muestres cual es el resultado re cada consulta y partimos de alli

Comment: @CarlosQuintero utilizo los corchetes porque segun lei necesito que al imprimir si guarde mantenimientos en enero y febrero me los muestre asi [Enero, 45], [Febrero, 5] y asi me los muestra ya que estos resultados los deseo usar para graficar en la variable $mante= Enero son 44 en Febrero son 9  y la variable $inme en Enero son 15 y en Febrero son 2 entonces lo que quiero es algo asi $resul Enero 44/(44+15) = 0.745 y en Febrero = 9/(9+2) = 0.818 básicamente esto es lo que espero  y que se repita en los otros meses si en ese mes se guardo X mantenimiento espero sea claro esta vez

Comment: Solo que quite lo que era de los meses porque pensé que por eso no me funciona la formula y lo deje así

Comment: echo "['".$row["Mes"]."',".$row["Mante"]."],"; de esta forma me imprime asi [Enero, 45] y solo deje que me tomara la parte del mantenimiento porque yo pensaba que porque iba lo del mes eso era lo que afectaba y no funcionara la formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El operador `+` en arreglos hace la unión de los elementos del arreglo, siendo que el orden de los operandos altera el resultado.

Lo que necesitas es hacer la operación elemento por elemento, algo como:

```
    foreach( $sam as $i => $m )
        $re[$i] = $m + $inme[$i];
```

Pero deberás procurar:

- Que los meses correspondan en cada índice.
- No agregar corchetes a los valores. Por que convertirá los valores en strings y no podrás hacer operaciones numéricas. Aquí aplica el principio de "separación de intereses", es decir, cuando hagas cálculos no te debería importar la presentación, si necesitas los corchetes en la vista manéjalo en  html.

Alternativamente -y a mi preferencia- puedes hacer el cálculo en un solo SQL. Algo como un subquery con agregación condicional:

```
SELECT anio
     , mes
     , Mante / (Mante + Inme) res
  FROM ( SELECT year(Fecha_soli) anio
              , month(Fecha_soli) mes
              , count( if( Tipo_mante != 'Correctivo Inmediato', 1, 0 ) ) Mante
              , count( if( Tipo_mante  = 'Correctivo Inmediato', 1, 0 ) ) Inme
           FROM solicitud_mante
           GROUP BY year(Fecha_soli)
                  , month(Fecha_soli)
       ) t;
```

El resto de los detalles -de presentación- los puedes manejar fácilmente en PHP.

Comment: Pero como podría hacer una sola consulta tomando datos del mismo campo? porque opte por hacer lo asi ya que en varios foros lei que no se podia hacer tal cosa

Comment: Amigo me sirvio